# Magento PayPal Duplicate Invoice Error

Tags: php, magento, paypal

Every once in a while a customer will get an error when attempting to submit an order that says **PayPal gateway has rejected request. The transaction was refused as a result of a duplicate invoice ID supplied.**  After digging into this a bit I believe I have narrowed down the problem.  In the most recent of cases, a customer had attempted to place an order 4 months ago and received an **Internal Error** from PayPal.  I learned from speaking with PayPal that this customer's credit card had been flagged.  When they attempted to place the first order, PayPal rejected it but still considered the Invoice ID that our Magento Store had provided "used".

Fast forward to today...same customer, new order.  Magento STILL had the old quote from September in the `sales_flat_quote` table.  When they logged in, it loaded the customer quote (which was still active) and attempted to use it for this order.  That resulted in the **Duplicate Invoice ID** error.

I see in the Mage_Sales_Model_Observer class that there is a `cleanExpiredQuotes` method that is called from a cron job.  However, this only effects quotes with "is_active" = 0.  Since this quote is considered active it never got cleared out.

So clearly there's a disconnect between the Magento code and PayPal.  But that's about as far as I've gotten with it.  Has anyone else experienced this?  If so, any suggestions?

### EDIT:

I've gotten a bit further with this.  I have added code to the checkout IndexController to catch the error and, if it's a Duplicate Invoice Error, it unsets the **reserved_order_id** in the quote a calls the **saveOrderAction** again.  This causes the quote to reserve a new order ID, which it then submits to PayPal.  The problem I'm having now is that when it tries the second time with the new Invoice Number, all the totals are 0.  I tried setting the **totals_collected_flag** to false so it re-collects the totals, but they are always 0 the second time through.  More specifically, the totals in the **Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Address** are 0, which is what the **Mage_Sales_Model_Order** ends up using.  The totals in the **Mage_Sales_Model_Quote** are correct, but they get overwritten in the `collectTotals()` method of the quote.

Obviously, after the first attempt, something is unsetting all the values, but I don't know what or where.  If anyone has any ideas I'd love to hear them!

Comment: Great question.  I've been running into this myself.  What version of Magento are you using?  I've seen this with Magento 1.4 and 1.5 (the version we're currently using).

Comment: We're on 1.5.1.0, but I'll probably be upgrading us in a month or two.  Will post back if I stop seeing this happen.

Comment: As I indicated in your answer, I did come up with a work-around, but I like your answer.  Ultimately, it's working now, I'm just surprised I had to make such changes.

Comment: https://www.rakeshjesadiya.com/error-10412-paypal-duplicate-invoice-php/ resolve the error by step given in the link

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What essentially what is happening is that magento is sending paypal an orderId (invoice number) that has already been paid for in the system.  This causes paypal to return a response that indicates that this invoice number is a duplicate.  So, what I'm doing here is trying to detect that message response, generate a new orderId, and resubmit to paypal for reprocessing.

Here is the action that starts the whole chain of sending information to magento.  It is located at 'Mage_Paypal_Controller_Express_Abstract'.  I modified the 'token' generated by the paypal response.  This token will contain information about the error that occured.

```
startAction(){
    ...
    $token = $this->_checkout->start(Mage::getUrl('*/*/return'), Mage::getUrl('*/*/cancel'));
    if ($token && $url = $this->_checkout->getRedirectUrl()) {
        $this->_initToken($token);
        ...
    }
}
```

to:

```
startAction(){
    ...
    $token = $this->_checkout->start(Mage::getUrl('*/*/return'), Mage::getUrl('*/*/cancel'));

    //while this token is invalid
    while (isset($token['error'])) {
        //generate a new token
        $token = $this->_checkout->start(Mage::getUrl('*/*/return'),Mage::getUrl('*/*/cancel'), TRUE);
    }
    if ($token['token'] && $url = $this->_checkout->getRedirectUrl()) {
        $this->_initToken($token['token']);
         ...
    }

}
```

This token is generated by the start() method in 'Mage_Paypal_Model_Express_Checkout'.  start() also handles the entire process of object manipulation.  Here, we will conditionally alter the productId.

the modified function will look like this:

```
public function start($returnUrl, $cancelUrl, $errorAgain = FALSE)
{
    $this->_quote->collectTotals();

    if (!$this->_quote->getGrandTotal() && !$this->_quote->hasNominalItems()) {
        Mage::throwException(Mage::helper('paypal')->__('PayPal does not support processing orders with zero amount. To complete your purchase, proceed to the standard checkout process.'));
    }
    if ($errorAgain) {
        Mage::log('why is this running?');
        $this->_quote->setReservedOrderId($this->_quote->getReservedOrderId($this->_quote));
        $this->_quote->reserveOrderId()->save();
    }
    //$this->_quote->setReservedOrderId($this->_quote->_getResource()->getReservedOrderId($this->_quote));
    //$this->_quote->setReservedOrderId($this->_quote->getReservedOrderId($this->_quote));
    $this->_quote->reserveOrderId()->save();
    // prepare API
    $this->_getApi();
    $this->_api->setAmount($this->_quote->getBaseGrandTotal())
        ->setCurrencyCode($this->_quote->getBaseCurrencyCode())
        ->setInvNum($this->_quote->getReservedOrderId())
        ->setReturnUrl($returnUrl)
        ->setCancelUrl($cancelUrl)
        ->setSolutionType($this->_config->solutionType)
        ->setPaymentAction($this->_config->paymentAction)
    ;
    if ($this->_giropayUrls) {
        list($successUrl, $cancelUrl, $pendingUrl) = $this->_giropayUrls;
        $this->_api->addData(array(
            'giropay_cancel_url' => $cancelUrl,
            'giropay_success_url' => $successUrl,
            'giropay_bank_txn_pending_url' => $pendingUrl,
        ));
    }

    $this->_setBillingAgreementRequest();

    if ($this->_config->requireBillingAddress == Mage_Paypal_Model_Config::REQUIRE_BILLING_ADDRESS_ALL) {
        $this->_api->setRequireBillingAddress(1);
    }

    // supress or export shipping address
    if ($this->_quote->getIsVirtual()) {
        if ($this->_config->requireBillingAddress == Mage_Paypal_Model_Config::REQUIRE_BILLING_ADDRESS_VIRTUAL) {
            $this->_api->setRequireBillingAddress(1);
        }
        $this->_api->setSuppressShipping(true);
    } else {
        $address = $this->_quote->getShippingAddress();
        $isOverriden = 0;
        if (true === $address->validate()) {
            $isOverriden = 1;
            $this->_api->setAddress($address);
        }
        $this->_quote->getPayment()->setAdditionalInformation(
            self::PAYMENT_INFO_TRANSPORT_SHIPPING_OVERRIDEN, $isOverriden
        );
        $this->_quote->getPayment()->save();
    }

    // add line items
    $paypalCart = Mage::getModel('paypal/cart', array($this->_quote));
    $this->_api->setPaypalCart($paypalCart)
        ->setIsLineItemsEnabled($this->_config->lineItemsEnabled)
    ;

    // add shipping options if needed and line items are available
    if ($this->_config->lineItemsEnabled && $this->_config->transferShippingOptions && $paypalCart->getItems()) {
        if (!$this->_quote->getIsVirtual() && !$this->_quote->hasNominalItems()) {
            if ($options = $this->_prepareShippingOptions($address, true)) {
                $this->_api->setShippingOptionsCallbackUrl(
                    Mage::getUrl('*/*/shippingOptionsCallback', array('quote_id' => $this->_quote->getId()))
                )->setShippingOptions($options);
            }
        }
    }

    // add recurring payment profiles information
    if ($profiles = $this->_quote->prepareRecurringPaymentProfiles()) {
        foreach ($profiles as $profile) {
            $profile->setMethodCode(Mage_Paypal_Model_Config::METHOD_WPP_EXPRESS);
            if (!$profile->isValid()) {
                Mage::throwException($profile->getValidationErrors(true, true));
            }
        }
        $this->_api->addRecurringPaymentProfiles($profiles);
    }

    $this->_config->exportExpressCheckoutStyleSettings($this->_api);

    // call API and redirect with token
    $response = $this->_api->callSetExpressCheckout();
    $token['token'] = $this->_api->getToken();
    $this->_redirectUrl = $this->_config->getExpressCheckoutStartUrl($token['token']);
    if ($response == 'duplicate') {
        $token['error'] = 'duplicate';
        return $token;
    } elseif (isset($token['error'])) {
        unset($token['error']);
    }
    $this->_quote->getPayment()->unsAdditionalInformation(self::PAYMENT_INFO_TRANSPORT_BILLING_AGREEMENT);
    $this->_quote->getPayment()->save();
    return $token;
}
```

Now, the final part handles the actual paypal call and response.  This is done with the call() function located at 'Mage_Paypal_Model_Api_Nvp'.

After the response is generated we shall check for the error response and, instead of redirecting, we shall simply return it up the chain.

located around line 997:

```
if ($response['L_SHORTMESSAGE0'] == 'Duplicate invoice') {
    return $response;
}
```

So it goes like this:

```
startaction()->start()->call()->start()->startaction()->redirect();
```

if there is a duplicate entry error it will do this..

```
startaction()->start()->call(error)->start()->call()->start()->staraction()->redirect();
```

Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: Thank you for this in depth answer.  Superficially this looks good, though I don't have the means of easily testing it.  I recently upgraded to 1.9 and still had this issue, so what I ended up doing was altering the saveOrder function in the checkout controller to re-call itself if this error gets triggered.  Just prior I unset the reserved order ID and re-reserve one, which increments the number.  This is much like your solution, just in the controller instead of the PP code.  Yours is probably more elegant ;).  Thanks for posting!  I'll accepted this answer since it's basically what I did.

Answer (score 4):

1. Log in to your Paypal account
2. Go to **[Profile > Payment Receiving Preferences](https://www.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_profile-pref)**
3. Under **Block accidental payments** select **No, allow multiple payments per invoice ID**

[image]

Comment: This is a little risky to flat out allow them, however I guess my solution does basically the same thing.  Thanks for posting this!  I didn't know about that setting, I'll keep that in mind.

Comment: I am not sure why it might be risky. Could you explain? IMHO it is risky to leave a customer blocked out by an error message without a chance to use the site and buy products.

Comment: It just feels risky to me to not have that check in place so a customer can't pay for an invoice twice.  But, as I said, my "fix" does essentially the same thing, though it does log the fact that it got the duplicate error so I can go back and track down any duplicate payments.  I agree that allowing a customer to make a purchase is of utmost importance, but angering them with duplicate charges doesn't help either.

Comment: Well, I understand your concern. But have you actually had a case of duplicate payment? I think this is mostly a false alarm. Perhaps the best thing is to report this bug to Magento (and maybe to PayPal too).

Comment: I believe this may be a necessary change when you have multiple Magento installations all pointed towards the same PayPal account. I've just deployed a fresh Magento installation and received the error from the new store. My guess, one of the early invoice IDs on the new installation overlapped with an early invoice ID from one of my existing installations... Unless you have something that keeps invoice IDs unique across multiple Magento installations, I don't know how you'd avoid this problem.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this may be a necessary change when you have multiple Magento installations all pointed towards the same PayPal account. I've just deployed a fresh Magento installation and received the error from the new store. My guess, one of the early invoice IDs on the new installation overlapped with an early invoice ID from one of my existing installations...

One option [as mentioned by @george here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29686012/680920) is to edit your PayPal settings, which will get you up and running ASAP. That does open the door for some risk though. What's probably better is to install a plugin such as [Custom Order Prefix](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/custom-order-prefix.html) on all of your Magento installations. That way each installation will pass invoice IDs with a different prefix despite the invoice IDs themselves overlapping.

Answer (score -1):

Haven't yet done this, but seems like installing this [Fooman extension](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/fooman-sameorderinvoicenumber.html) would potentially fix the quotes using the wrong/old Order #.  Does that work for you?

Love to hear either way.  I'm getting set to tackle this and make our PayPal exceptions more legible (using some of PayPal's explanations from [here](https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_api_nvp_errorcodes).  So if you do find it helps, would love to know.

Edit:
Found some further info [here](http://www.bigdune.net/geek-blog/3-magento/6-magento-paypal-ipn-wrong-order-id.html).  Apparently the Fooman extension helps, but doesn't fix the problems completely.  Does this help solve your problem?

Edit:
Per the [change log for Magento 1.7.0.0](http://www.magentocommerce.com/download/release_notes#Release%20Notes%20-%20Magento%201.7.0.0%20%28Apr%2024,%202012%29) (which came out in April), they think they've fixed the problem:

```
Fixed: “Wrong order ID” exception in PayPal Express module under heavy load
```

Can anyone confirm that upgrading to Magento 1.7 does indeed fix the problem?  Every time I've looked at it, it does seem to be a PayPal Express issue (our payments normally go through PayPal Pro and that doesn't seem to have errors).

Comment: No, we already had the Fooman extension and it didn't help.  I am 99% sure the problem is caused by the following...  When a customer attempts an order and it fails, PP considers the Invoice # as already used while Magento does not.  The next time the customer attempts an order, Magento finds the old record in the quote table and attempts to use it.  PP returns the dup error, which Magento ignores and continues to use the same number.  I have "patched" it by incrementing the number if I receive the dup error, but it doesn't address the root cause, so customers still see at least one error.

Comment: If you find any good info or a real fix for this, please post it here as this is still an issue for us.

Comment: Brian, just found out that Magento 1.7 may have the fix (see my edit).  Have you tried upgrading to it yet?

Comment: Thanks, acorncom, that's great info!  I haven't tried upgrading yet, and that's probably not in the cards any time soon.  Upgrading Magento can be a nightmare.  Already did it once going from 1.4.2.0 to 1.5.0.1.  I don't look forward to another upgrade any time soon.  Have you confirmed that this indeed fixes the problem?  If so, I'd love to know what they changed and maybe apply that to the 1.5.0.1 code.

Comment: This problem is not fixed in 1.7.

Comment: @acorncom Just got a solution working -- I suppose i'll post it even though OP is probably long gone!

Comment: This happens in Magento 1.9.1.0 as well.

Comment: This won't solve the problem if you have multiple Magento installations pointed at a single PayPal account.

Answer (score -1):

**CAUSE OF THE PROBLEM:**

The presented solution are **only workarounds** for the underlying problem which is that the `increment_last_id` for invoices is lagging behind the `increment_last_id` for orders.

There is nothing wrong with the Magento code, it is the **Database** that is in a problematic state. This usually happens after a Magento update.

To fix the problem you just have to set your invoice `increment_last_id` to the same value as the order one.

**UPDATE**

As pointed out by others, it is normal that these ids are not in sync, but if the invoice id is too much BEHIND the order id (and not the other way around) problems with PayPal can occur (more information [here](http://www.magetricks.com/tricks/how-to-fix-paypal-this-invoice-has-already-been-paid-message)).
Before turning down this solution, just try it out, it worked perfectly for me and others.

**HOW TO FIX:**

Use your preferred DB management tool ([PHPmyAdmin](https://www.phpmyadmin.net/), [Adminer](http://www.adminer.org/), ...) go to the `eav_entity_store` table and check the values. It should look sth. like this:

```
+-----------------+----------------+----------+------------------+-------------------+
| entity_store_id | entity_type_id | store_id | increment_prefix | increment_last_id |
+-----------------+----------------+----------+------------------+-------------------+
|               1 |              5 |        1 |                1 |         100001708 |
|               2 |              6 |        1 |                1 |         100000926 |
|               3 |              8 |        1 |                1 |         100000888 |
|               4 |              7 |        1 |                1 |         100000054 |
+-----------------+----------------+----------+------------------+-------------------+
```

The interesting values here are:

1. ORDER increment_last_id:  entity_type_id = 5 (100001708)
2. INVOICE increment_last_id: entity_type_id = 6 (100000926)

So the only thing we have to do here is set the INVOICE value to the one of the ORDER value. We can do this with any db management tool, or directly with the sql command

```
UPDATE eav_entity_store
  SET increment_last_id="100001708"
  WHERE entity_type_id="6" AND store_id="1"
```

If you have multiple stores you will have to change the store_id.

This answer is based on the info from [this article](http://www.springbot.com/2015/03/fix-paypal-invoice-already-paid/).

Comment: I think it is quite normal that `order_id` and `invoice_id` are not sync.

Comment: Yes, but a problem with paypal can occur when the INVOICE id is behind the order id. more information here: http://www.magetricks.com/tricks/how-to-fix-paypal-this-invoice-has-already-been-paid-message